# NGINX - django subdomain proxy_pass keeps redirecting

Tags: nginx, web-server, configuration, django

I'm trying to add subdomain news.abc.com for my django application and forward it to example.com/news/
And NGINX keeps redirecting whatever i do.
My current config is

```
server {
    server_name news.example.com www.news.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://www.example.com/news/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; 

}
```

And it just keeps redirecting me to example.com/news, but i just want content from that page without redirecting

Comment: Why do you think nginx is redirecting the request? There is no redirect shown in this configuration.

Comment: You need to fix the application at `https://www.example.com/news/` so that it doesn't send the redirect.